# Apply bootstrap to a specific meteor template only

Tags: css, meteor

Is it possible to apply bootstrap to a specific meteor template only let say bootstrap will only render the login template and not outside the template? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: this is not possible. Meteor automatically merges and minimizes all [css](/questions/tagged/css) files in the app to a single CSS file. You could move around this by declaring very specific styling to your different templates, but when you use Bootstrap it's hardly doable since it's just too large.

There's a [topic on the official Meteor forum](https://forums.meteor.com/t/loading-different-css-files-selectively/3824) about this subject though. With a bit of a workaround you should be able to apply different stylesheets to different templates.

Check the [8th post in the thread](https://forums.meteor.com/t/loading-different-css-files-selectively/3824/8) specifically.